# Border around drawable

Tags: android

I have this drawable I'm using for a 2 button like so

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:text="No"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_negative"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_trans_blue"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:text="Yes"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_positive"

    android:background="@drawable/btn_trans_blue"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

**btn_trans_blue.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/fublue" />

    <item
        android:state_activated="true"
        android:drawable="@color/fublue" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/custom_button" />
</selector>
```

**custom_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And what I need is both buttons to have a 1dp border on the top (which that gives), but the negative button to have a 1dp border on the right.

How can I add this to the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the *border* with another shape thats painted below the body color and then add an offset for the top shape only on the sides you want borders. For instance to have a red border only on top, you can do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Border -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#f000"></solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Body -->
    <item android:top="2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ffafafaf"></solid>
        </shape> 
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Or if you need a border (with dashed or whatever) set that border on the first item (the one that will be below) and then the offset on the second item (the one on top) will reveal that border.

Comment: How would I get the border to show on the top and the right side at the same time?

Comment: That's what I get for trusting the preview!, I tried that but the preview looked so wrong I didn't bother compiling it >.<. Is it possible to have a transparent background, so whatever the underlaying colour is that's what's shown?